# Where can i find an exhaustive list of svn error codes

Tags: svn, documentation, error-code

I couldn't find any place to look up all svn error codes? - I just had to google 'svn E200005' manually.
Shouldn't there be an exhaustive list somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean [this](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/api/1.8/svn__error__codes_8h_source.html)?

[This](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/api/1.8/svn__error__codes_8h.html) is a *very* friendly documentation of them also.

Comment: Well, thank you sir, I had found that too, but tbh I had hoped for a friendly document instead of the plain c header file - it only states all codes, no actual documentation when they occur or whatever.

Comment: @IARI I added their documentation

Comment: ah, thank you, that's better, I had not found that :)

Comment: That list doesn't help much. I see an error E160028 here. So what "friendly" error constant does it correspond to? The error text I have here does not even match the strings specified. Therefor I must conclude: This list is not of much help :-(